# How to submit form in new tab using execute_script

Tags: python, selenium

```
browser.get('https://www.example.com')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click(), 'new_window'", browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submitButton"]'))
```

This code opens a new tab on some sites. For others it clicks without opening a new tab.

How can I make this open a new tab consistently?

**update**

```
browser.execute_script('window.open(arguments[0].click());', browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submitButton"]'))
```

Opens a new tab but executes the click in the original window. Leaving the new tab empty

Comment: `submitButton`  is a link? I mean like `<a id="submitButton" href="#">link text</a>`

Comment: `<input class="search-button icon-search" id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Search" data-original-title="" title="">`

Comment: Can you clarify: do you want to click something to open new tab or you want to open some specific URL to click button there? Describe your scenario in more details

Comment: click something to open in a new tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'window.open(arguments[0].click());'` just making two operations (opening new tab and clicking button) which are not really related

You can try to do something like below to force opening new tab on clicking Submit button:

```
input_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submitButton"]')
form = input_button.find_element_by_xpath('./ancestor::form')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].target="_blank";', form)
input_button.click()
```

Comment: this solution throws an exception, caused by a popup that doesn't go away

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <input id="submitButton" class="search-button icon-search active" type="submit"> is not clickable at point (729.2000122070312,43) because another element <div id="monetate_lightbox_mask" class=""> obscures it`

Comment: @Rhys , try `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', input_button)` instead of `input_button.click()`

Comment: wow this works. What is `input_button.find_element_by_xpath('./ancestor::form')` if I may as?

Comment: Input fields of type submit are used to submit forms. So with `'./ancestor::form'` we can locate `form` element wherever it is. And with `'arguments[0].target="_blank";'` we just force `form` to be submitted in new tab